# Error while trying to iterate JSON array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have JSON file, which i load in js code without problems using `JSON.parse()` (A reduced example of the file shown here, it's **25 items long**):

```
{
    "List": [
    {  "Term": "Tos"   },
    {  "Term": "Gripa" },
    {  "Term": "Catarro"}, 
    {  "Term": "Flemas"}
    ]
}
```

When I iterate it accessing one item per iteration I have no problems, but when i try to increase the index to access to items per iteration it throws the following error (Comment in code shows the line with the problem):

> console.log(searchTerms[j].Term);
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Term' of undefined

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(searchTermsFile);
var searchTerms = JSON.parse(data);
searchTerms = searchTerms.List;
for(var j=0;j<searchTerms.length;j+=4)
{
    console.log(searchTerms[j].Term);
    j+=1;
    console.log(searchTerms[j].Term); /****<---- THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR ****/
}
```

Comment: can't you wait for the next cycle? or do you need inside of the loop an access to the next item?

Comment: i need to access 5 items per iteration

Comment: you don't need `j+=1;` since you already have a for loop. When you read, in this case, 3, it'll go to 4 and try to access `searchTerms[4]` which doesn't exist

Comment: @danielgoba84 tell us the requirement

Comment: well this is a simplified code, i need to access 5 items per iteration, i use them to create a request, i will also concatenate them to create a unique file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object contains 4 `Term` and your `for` loop count to 4 but `j+=1` in last iteration make `j=5` and there is no object in `searchTerms[5]`.This is why your code doesn't work.
I write sample program.I hope this helps you:

```js
var data = {
    "List": [
        {"Term": "1"},
        {"Term": "2"},
        {"Term": "3"},
        {"Term": "4"},
        {"Term": "5"},
        {"Term": "6"},
        {"Term": "7"},
        {"Term": "8"},
        {"Term": "9"},
        {"Term": "10"},
        {"Term": "11"},
        {"Term": "12"}
    ]
};

function test() {
  var searchTerms = data.List;
  var j = 0;
  var currentFiveObject = [];
  for (j = 0; j < searchTerms.length; j += 5) {
    currentFiveObject = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (j + i < searchTerms.length)
        currentFiveObject.push(searchTerms[j + i])
      else
        break;
    }
    console.log(currentFiveObject);
  }
}
test();
```

Comment: ok ill edit the code, but that's not the problem, i simplified the JSON, to save space, it's 25 items long, also the code was simplified, (will edit) 'j+=5' and inside the loop i update 'j' and  when 'j' is increased and try to access the next element, even in the first iteration it throws the error

Comment: @danielgoba84 I added sample code for your case.Please test that

Answer (score 0):

You could use a default object, which resolves the error, but returns `undefined` as well.

```
j += 1;
console.log((searchTerms[j] || {}).Term);
```

The other way to deal with indices out of range, is to use a check in advance and prevent from using an index greater than the last index value.

```
if (j < searchTerms.length) {
    // process item
    console.log(searchTerms[j].Term);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are incrementing `j` and then checking , however since you are iterating till the `length - 1` it will go out of bounds after `j += 1`, try

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(searchTermsFile);
var searchTerms = JSON.parse(data);
searchTerms = searchTerms.List;for(var j=0;j<searchTerms.length - 1;j++)
{
 console.log(searchTerms[j].Term);
 j+=1;
 console.log(searchTerms[j].Term); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(searchTermsFile);
var searchTerms = JSON.parse(data);
var i = 0;
searchTerms = searchTerms.List;for(var j=0;j<searchTerms.length;j++)
{
 i = j
 console.log((searchTerms[i] || {}).Term);
 i +=1;
 console.log((searchTerms[i] || {}).Term); 
}
```

Comment: do not understand how this should work, can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

The real problem you're facing is that your j-index is requiring an item that's not contained in your JSON object. I found no reason for your cycle to increase your index variable in the middle of logging your Terms.

If that index increment is intended, then you need to consider if the value of j is equal or larger than searchTerms length before using it as the index accessor.

Remove it or deal with it.